# QtCreator won't open any project after a crash

Tags: qt-creator

After a crash of QtCreator it won't open any project anymore.

If I try to open a project (that worked perfectly well before the crash) the QtCreator seems to ignore me (I tried several ways of opening a project through the QtCreator).

If I open the QtCreator directly via a *.pro file it opens the project file as plain text without any syntax-highlighting.

If I try creating a new project it tells me "*No valid kits found*". None of the solutions I found to this problem helped me, though.

---

To fix the problem I've tried:

- restarting the Computer ;-)
- cloning the auto-detected compiler settings and verified each path

---

I'm using **QtCreator 3.0.0** with **MinGW 4.8 32bit** based on **Qt 5.2.0** (all precompiled)

I would like to avoid a reinstallation of QtCreator, if possible.

---

#### Solution:

I fixed the problem by myself - I figured out one of my config files got corrupted; see full answer below.

Comment: It's this sort of issue that makes Qt Creator not exactly stand out as being a robust IDE.  What a hassle, especially with deadlines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked the issue down by myself:

- In the [FAQ](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-faq.html) I found the entry how to reset all QtCreator settings. After doing this the QtCreator worked again.
- I wrote I didn't want to reinstall the QtCreator (because of the settings), so I restored the old config from the bin and tried deleting the corrupted config file only.
- When I finally deleted `QtProject/qtcreator/mimetypes/modifiedmimetypes.xml` QtCreator worked again. I remember messing with the mimetypes prior to the crash, so I guess that's it.